Why are the last two values in this array always valid?
I was hacking around with stacks in C to demonstrate something to a friend. I understand that the functions below return pointers to garbage memory, and so we can't rely on them. That was the point of the demonstration.
#include <stdio.h>

int *oneToTen();
int *elevenToTwenty();

int main() {

  int *arr = oneToTen();

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
  }

  elevenToTwenty();
  printf("\n\n\n");

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}

int *oneToTen() {
  int arr[10];

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    arr[i] = i + 1;
  }

  return arr;
}

int *elevenToTwenty() {
  int arr[10];

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    arr[i] = i + 11;
  }

  return arr;
}

The output is basically as expected. We get garbage memory, and calling the second function changes the memory returned by the first function.
1
1
47405968
1
1833808032
1
-2092245084
-1687584767
9
10



43154832
1
47405968
1
1833808032
1
-2092245084
-1687584767
19
20

But there's a weird thing happening. Every time I run this function, the last two elements of this array never get garbage-d out. All the other array elements turn to garbage, but never the last two. Why is this?
I'm, not SUPER familiar with what happens to memory after it gets popped off the stack, so I don't really know how to answer this question. My guess is that it perhaps has to do with there being 8 values, so it's maybe a power-of-two thing?
EDIT: I tried changing the number of things in the array, and it's always the last two elements that remain the same

You return a pointer to local variables. The life-tine of those variables end when the function return. The pointer will immediately become invalid. Please read more about scope and life-time in your beginners material.

If you want to see exactly what is going on, you can switch your debugger to display the assembly language instructions and run one instruction at a time, while monitoring the values in memory and all CPU registers. What exactly is happening probably depends on which compiler you are using and with which options you are invoking the compiler, for example with which optimization level. That is the nature of undefined behavior.

@someprgrammerdude I'm not asking why the memory gets garbage-d out. I'm asking why the last two do NOT get garbage'd out.

The program has undefined behavior. You may get anything when you print the values - or nothing - or a crash. Asking why you get certain values isn't particularly meaningful.

If you increase the number of elements in the arrays, you may see a different behavior. Perhaps looking at the assembly code for your implementation could give some hints.

When you invoke undefined behavior, anything can happen. They can be 'garbaged out' or they could be not 'garbaged out.'

@CPlus Makes sense. It's just that the pattern I've seen after doing this demo a bunch of times is that the last two elements persist, and I wanted to see if there's some specific reason for that

I believe that you will find this answer helpful. Although it talks about C++, most of this also applies to C.

@TheInfiniteOne Realistically, my guess is that none of the code afterwards happens to place variables in that particular memory, overwriting the values previously there.

'garbaged out.' is not a guarantee and is dependent on implementation and environment details. For common implementations in this circumstance, it is an expected effect from the memory that used to be used for one purpose being reused for another. Your printf calls happen to using/overwriting some, but not all of the same memory location. Different printf calls or other things could overwrite different amounts. Normal. Also  nothing that you can rely on exactly how it comes out.

When I test your code on the compiler gcc with default compiler options, I get a segmentation fault (i.e. your program crashes). When I do the same on the compiler clang, it does not crash, but the results are very different than yours. This shows that you cannot rely on anything when dealing with undefined behavior.

"I'm asking why the last two do NOT get garbage'd out."  They will be, but nothing says that it has to happen immediately.

The question is:

Why are the last two values in this array always valid?

The printf function happens to re-use the same stack memory as was allocated for arr. Bottom line, it's the same stack and same memory. printf happens to only overwrite 8 * sizeof(int) bytes of memory before printing the value of int.
The last two values of this array will not "always" be valid. Any other compiler version, compiler options, platform, environment may change the result significantly. Your program by itself is invalid, you might be interested in Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior .

if there's some specific reason for that

No. It just happens to happen. "If you put an apple in the garbage, it's still an apple". Memory hold values and will continue to hold until overwritten.

And the fun thing about that last line is you don't know when that memory will be overwritten.

If you compile it with warnings enabled, for example in gcc, you will see:
a.c: In function ‘oneToTen’:
a.c:31:10: warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]
   31 |   return arr;
a.c: In function ‘elevenToTwenty’:
a.c:41:10: warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]
   41 |   return arr;
      |          ^~~

From warnings, you will be able to find the problem. Local variables in functions are automatic variables and will be destroyed on function exit.
use pointers and dynamic allocation to solve the problem:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 10

int *oneToTen() {
  int *arr = malloc(SIZE * sizeof (int));

  for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
    arr[i] = i + 1;

  return arr;
}

int *elevenToTwenty() {
  int *arr = malloc(SIZE * sizeof (int));

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    arr[i] = i + 11;

  return arr;
}

int main() {
  int *arr = oneToTen();

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
  free(arr);

  printf("\n\n\n");

  arr = elevenToTwenty();

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
  free(arr);

  return 0;
}

You said: It just happens to happen. "If you put an apple in the garbage, it's still an apple". Memory hold values and will continue to hold until overwritten.
When you call your function, the arr will be in stack. On function return, depends on compiler implementation and ABI, will be pushed to stack or register or some location whose address sent by caller.
Then you call printf, so its arguments will be pushed to stack. You used loops and its implementation depends on compiler and may be consume stack. So with greate probabilty your arr contents overwritten here by printf or loop.

I'm not trying to solve the problem. I know how to solve it; I'm trying to analyze the behavior of the stck

Ok, sorry. local variables will be created in stack and after function exit, they are invalid. But static variables, global variables and malloced variables will be created in heap and they stay.
